# Applying Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is the first time that I'm doing a proof-problem on my own and I'm not really sure how to check if my answer is correct, so I was wondering if someone could tell me with certainty if my proof is correct.

The problem states:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function (on its entire domain) such that $f(0) = f(1) = f(2)$. Prove that there exists some point $x_0 \in (0, 2)$ such that $f''(x_0) = 0$.

So I developed my proof based on Rolle's theorem that states that if a function $f$ is continous on a closed interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on an open interval $(a, b)$ and if $f(a) = f(b)$ then there exists some point $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

Proof:

1. $f$ is differentiable $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, meaning $f$ must be differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$
2. $f$ is differentiable $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ meaning $f$ must be continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ meaning $f$ must be continuous on $[0, 1]$ and $[1, 2]$.
3. $f(0) = f(1)$ and $f(1) = f(2)$.

From 1., 2. and 3. we conclude that $f$ satisfies the conditions of Rolle's theorem for both of these intervals, meaning:
$\exists c_1 \in (0, 1) : f'(c_1) = 0$ and $\exists c_2 \in (1, 2) : f'(c_2) = 0$

Let $F(x) = f'(x)$. We know that the original function is twice differentiable $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore $F(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ meaning it must be differentiable on $(c_1, c_2)$ also meaning it must be continuous on $[c_1, c_2]$.

Now, since $f'(c_1) = f'(c_2) = 0$, the function $F(x)$ satisfies the conditions of Rolle's theorem (on the interval $(c_1, c_2)$) meaning :

$\exists x_0 \in (c_1, c_2) \subset(0, 2): F'(x_0) = f''(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: Hello there. Please do not type all the proof in math mode. This makes the post hard to read. Just type those symbols in mathjax. . Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It didn't look like this in the preview. Could be a bug or something

Comment: Usually, new users have to be encouraged to use mathjax. In your case, I'd say you that you are using mathjax *too much*. Please, write text without mathjax.

Comment: After a cursory reading, i would say the proof seems fine. Although it can be neater.

Comment: I've edited your answer, now it's more legible. I would say your proof is right

Comment: @rldias Thanks for saving me the trouble :)

Comment: Your proof is solid.